# loss of console graphical screen until Ctrl-Alt-F1

Tags: rhel, console

having a clean install of RHEL 8.8 x86-64, onto a Dell server with 192gb of RAM, and fully updated, and having `systemctl set-default graphical.target`... it is NFS exporting a `/data` folder.  It exports it over a 1gbps network and also over a 100gbps infiniband network.  I have not concluded as of yet, but it seems like when (me being the only user on the system) is doing a copy from it (server-A) to server-B {the backup server} that the console of Server-A who is the NFS-Server will lose the basic Redhat graphical login screen.  It will go to the runlevel 3 (multi-user.target) *style* that is all text and will have what looks like audit information.  It does have the USB disconnect/reconnect message that I am used to seeing when I disconnect & reconnect the usb keyboard & mouse.

But when the console goes to this state, I cannot type anything until I first do a Ctrl-Alt-F2 to get a run level 3 looking login prompt (which will work) and then if I do Ctrl-Alt-F1 then the graphical login screen will come back and is functional.  Some amount of time passes (haven't logged what actions I am doing during that time or if it will happen just after some amount of idle time) the loss of console graphical login will happen again.  Does anyone know what is happening, why, and what to correct so that the graphical console login is always present?

Note: with `auditd` on there was this problem more harshly and unrecoverable, but I have since disabled `auditd` and this graphical console loss still happens but I can recover it with Ctrl-Alt-F1.  I ultimately have to re-enable auditd.